# How to get "actions" data in MessageResponse Watson Assistant Java client

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I am using IBM Watson Assistant Java client to develop a client application:

```
Assistant service = new Assistant("2018-02-16");
```

I have read the recommended approach to process client side actions triggers from workspace:

[https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions?cm_sp=dw-bluemix-*-nospace-*-answers](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions?cm_sp=dw-bluemix-_-nospace-_-answers)

But I can't find where to get the "actions" content I enter in the node as described in that page, in the MessageResponse object where response is returned (it has intents, response, contexts... but no "actions")

How should client know if the workspace node requests the execution of an action?

Answer (score 2):

"Actions" is something you create by yourself by opening the JSON Editor. The idea is that if you cannot catch something through context, you can send additional "actions" flag to your backend. Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
  "context": {
    "request_type": "@requesttype"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Your appointment is confirmed"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    },
    "action": {
      "period": "multi",
      "user": "outsider"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my question really is "How to get “actions” data in MessageResponse Watson Assistant Java client?"

Comment: You will catch the "actions" as you catch "context" in your backend. I'm not much familiar with Java but have a look at the sample app by IBM. Follow it and change the code to Java https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-simple

Comment: Thanks Hannan. The problem seems that if you use the official Java client by IBM the actions value is ignored, unlike the context which is correctly parsed in a Java property. Probably that Java client needs to be extended to support the "actions" feature. Let's see if IBM can help us on this should they read this.